# Symfony JWT The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: symfony, routes, jwt

I installed symfony version 6.3.1 with jwt and followed the instructions on the symfony page. However, when I try to login_check route with Postman, it doesn't find the route.

```
#security.yml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                username_path: email
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

```
#routes.yml
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

kernel:
    resource: ../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

```
#lexit_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 43200 # 12 Stunden
    user_identity_field: email
```

Already read several posts on stackoverflow but nothing helped. Is it maybe because of the newest version of Symfony?

Comment: I installed an older version of Symfony skeleton. AND I wrote plain password in ENV for JWT_PASSPHRASE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to add this:

```
# config/routes.yaml
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```